# The option selection in the Select box is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

The option selection in the Select box is not available.I don't know what the cause is. If you check the value by notifying, the first option is "12. Selecting "36" also outputs "12"

```
<form action="{{ route('penpal.index', ['list'=>$list,'page' => $page]) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" style="height:35px; width:80%" name="list" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="12">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twelve')</option>
                <option value="24">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twenty_four')</option>
                <option value="36">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.thirty_six')</option>
            </select>
        </form>


 alert($("#inputState").val());
```

Comment: Where are you checking the output? If your using `alert()`, then it will always output 12. `alert()` is a javascript function so it will always alert the value that is selected on page load, which for the above HTML will always be 12 as it is the first option. If you check the post request using PHP you should get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is wrong with your code. you just dont get the logic properly. here is a modify version of your code i wrote. if its of help to you, vote me. thanx

```
//the blade form. the javascript gets the value of the selected item, assign it to the input box and submit your form automatically.

    <form action="{{ route('penpal.index', ['list'=>$list,'page' => $page]) }}" method="post" id="submitForm">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select id="inputState" class="form-control" style="height:35px; width:80%" name="list">
     <option value="">-Please Select-</option>                          
      <option value="12">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twelve')</option>
        <option value="24">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twenty_four')</option>
        <option value="36">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.thirty_six')</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valueid" name="id" value="">
    </form>

//javascript code 
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#inputState").change(function(e){
       var value= e.target.value;
       //alert(value);
       document.getElementById('valueid').value = value; //assign select value to input field.
       $('#submitForm').submit(); //submit form

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: you can uncomment the alert(value) to be sure the value is displaying after which you comment it back.